# Selecting identical items based on shared foreign IDs they have

Tags: mysql

A database has collections of products; each collected product has a price recorded at the moment of being added to a collection, with a few other values.

```
// `collections_products`

id collection_id group product_id option_id price
1  1             0     56         0         3.1920
2  1             0     56         54        1.2000
3  1             0     56         55        2.4000
4  1             0     56         56        3.6000
5  1             0     56         57        4.8000
6  1             0     56         58        6.0000
7  1             0     57         0         3.1920
8  1             0     57         54        1.2000

11  10           0     56         0         3.1920
12  10           0     56         54        1.2000
13  10           0     56         55        2.4000
14  10           0     56         56        3.6000
15  10           0     56         57        4.8000
16  10           0     56         58        6.0000
17  10           0     57         0         3.1920
18  10           0     57         54        1.2000

21  100          0     56         0         9.9999
22  100          0     56         54        9.9999
23  100          0     56         55        9.9999
24  100          0     56         56        9.9999
25  100          0     56         57        9.9999
26  100          0     56         58        9.9999
27  100          0     57         0         9.9999
28  100          0     57         54        9.9999


31  1000         0     56         0         3.1920
32  1000         0     56         54        1.2000
33  1000         0     56         55        2.4000
34  1000         0     56         56        3.6000

36  1000         0     56         58        6.0000
37  1000         0     57         0         3.1920
38  1000         0     57         54        1.2000
```

Having some `collection_id`, I need to find other identical, duplicate collections (having identical content, i.e. same products, groups and options at same prices; order not important) to a given one.

In the examples above:

- the set of rows with `collection_id` 10 (set B) is a duplicate of the set of rows with `collection_id` 1 (set A); for every row in A there is another row in B with an identical `group product_id option_id price`, and A and B have the same number of rows
- the set of rows with `collection_id` 100 is NOT a duplicate of any other because all the prices are different
- the set of rows with `collection_id` 1000 is NOT a duplicate of any other because the count of rows are different (row id 35 is missing compared to `collection_id` 1)

Came up with:

- Have a select query looking for other collections based on what common IDs and values they have, all in one SQL statement, but unsure if this is at all possible with MySQL
- Calculate a checksum of each collection's result set (group, product_id, option_id, price of each row, together), store it as `collections.checksum`, re-calculate each time there's movement inside a collection. When searching, get the checksum of the collection I have and select by that checksum.

Researched the checksum idea. Found:

- [MySQL rows checksum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35196807/mysql-rows-checksum) & [mySQL: get hash value for each row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330799/mysql-get-hash-value-for-each-row): checksums the individual rows, but not a result set
- [Checksum of SELECT results in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955776/checksum-of-select-results-in-mysql): uses CRC32 and has an *Expected collisions* warning, which looks reasonable

Don't want to reinvent the wheel. Surprised I can't find anything reusable, unless I'm looking in a wrong direction.

What would be the right way to approach this? Please advice

**UPDATE** I'm not looking to delete any collections, even if they're duplicates. I need to combine them instead. This is a half-made-up example, sorry if it doesn't make 100% sense

Comment: You mean match an entire collection with another and see it bot have exact same rows?

Comment: @aexl Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57712189/2469308

Comment: Surely you're looking for rows that have the same `(group, product_id, option_id, price)` and a different id, and you're wanting to keep only the highest id (most recent)?

Comment: @CaiusJard No, I'm not looking to delete duplicates, but actually combine them. Edited the question to (hopefully) make that more obvious. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: What does COMBINE mean? add their prices together? average their prices?

Comment: @CaiusJard It does not matter (I mean it will complicate the question). I need to know their `collection_id`s. That's it.

Comment: So you're looking for rows that have the same (group, product_id, option_id, price) and a different collection_id? (But all the rows in a collection operate in totality)

Comment: I have some `collection_id`. I'm looking for different `collection_id`(s), if any. I don't need the rows themselves, as long as I'm sure those rows have identical `product_id`, `option_id`, `group`, `price` as the reference collection.

Comment: May I edit your question to add some detail that I think will help?

Comment: A fresh set of eyes always helps, thanks. Will I be able to correct if there's a misunderstanding?

Comment: @CaiusJard sure, thank you! (will delete this comment later to avoid cluttering)

Comment: I completed my edit; please review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT `product_id`, `option_id`, `group`, `price`, COUNT(*) as count_occurrences 
FROM `collections_products`
GROUP BY `product_id`, `option_id`, `group`, `price`
HAVING count_occurrences > 1;
```

This will give you all (product_id, option_id, price) combinations that occur more than once in your dataset. If you also want IDs of relevant rows, you can do a subquery with `JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT cp.`id` FROM
(SELECT `product_id`, `option_id`, `group`, `price`, COUNT(*) as count_occurrences 
FROM `collections_products`
GROUP BY `product_id`, `option_id`, `group`, `price`
HAVING count_occurrences > 1) t1
LEFT JOIN `collections_products` cp
ON t1.`product_id` = cp.`product_id` 
AND t1.`option_id` = cp.`option_id` 
AND t1.`group` = cp.`group`
AND t1.`price` = cp.`price`;
```

**UPD:**

To get the collection IDs that contain the same products as given collection, you'll need something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.`collection_id` FROM
(SELECT `collection_id`,`product_id`, `option_id`, `group`, `price`
FROM `collections_products`
WHERE `collection_id`=?) t1
LEFT JOIN `collections_products` t2
ON t1.`product_id`=t2.`product_id`
AND t1.`option_id`=t2.`option_id`
AND t1.`group`=t2.`group`
AND t1.`price`=t2.`price`
AND t1.`collection_id`<>t2.`collection_id`;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Sorry, I missed something in my question: I need to search for duplicate collections based on a given `collection_id`. Edited it just now.

Comment: @aexl I'm not sure I completely understand your question then. The first thing that comes into my mind would be adding `WHERE colledtion_id=?` clause to the query after `FROM collections_products` line in both cases. This will give you all rows with the same product, option, group and price within a specific collection. Is this what you need?

Comment: I need to find other collections having the same content as a given collection. Content = same products, options, groups and prices.